# extract specific data from respone bash

Tags: bash, curl

now i send curl to website
i want print only specific  data

example
this is part of respone code

```
<tr>
<td>USER</td>
<td><pre class="sf-dump" id="1962752086" data-indent-pad="  ">"<span class="sf-dump-str" title="7 characters">max</span>"
</pre><script>Sfdump("1962752086")</script>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>CITY</td>
<td><pre class="sf-dump" id="1962752086" data-indent-pad="  ">"<span class="sf-dump-str" title="7 characters">home</span>"
</pre><script>Sfdump("1962752086")</script>
</td>
</tr>
```

i want print

```
user : max
city : home
```

this is the code but only print
user
city

how can i print the span value for custom  like city and user

```
#!/bin/bash

curl -X POST -d "form_data" https://example.com/ | grep -E '<td>USER|<td>CITY' | awk -F'<td>' '{ print $2 }' | awk -F'</td>' '{ print $1 }'
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the HTML is well-formed XML, then [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) can work:

```bash
curl ... \
| xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//tr' -v 'td[1]' -o ':' -v 'td/pre/span' -n \
| awk 'BEGIN {FS = OFS = ":"} {$1 = tolower($1); print}'
```

```
user:max
city:home
```

Comment: the code didnot work with me i got error
`
 -:2.17: Extra content at the end of the document
            <td>DB_USERNAME</td>
 `           ^
this the code i used 
`
 #!/bin/bash

  curl -X POST -d "form_data" http://example.com/ | grep -E '<td>USER|<td>CITY' | xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//tr' -v 'td[1]' -o ':' -v 'td/pre/span' -n \
  | awk 'BEGIN {FS = OFS = ":"} {$1 = tolower($1); print}'
`
certinly the respone is big html code 
so i try to extract only spesfic data
but i fail

Comment: Are you awk/grep-ing the HTML _before_ passing it to xmlstarlet? xmlstarlet is an XML parser, to you have to have a well-formed document.